# Drop rows if value is before in any column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I need to drop rows from a df if a value appeared in a row before, but in any of the two first columns.

My df looks like this:

```
    id_a  id_b   value
0    NWS   HRD   21.06
1    HPE   ZRF  170.13
2    BAN   NWS  244.44
3    HBI   BCT  304.37
4    JFK   AQE  314.12
5    AQE   KEY  324.82
6    NWS   KLM  314.12
```

For example, NWS is in rows 0, 2, and 6, but not always in column `id_a` as it is also in column `id_b`. AQE is in row 4 and 5, in different columns each time. How can I drop a row if an `id` appeared before, no matter if it was in column `id_a` or `id_b`?

After all, I would like to have a new df with only the first appearance of each id, in whichever column that first observation is.

The ideal df should look like this:

```
    id_a  id_b   value
0    NWS   HRD   21.06
1    HPE   ZRF  170.13
3    HBI   BCT  304.37
4    JFK   AQE  314.12
```

I know I could do `drop_duplicates()` subsetting by `id_a` first and `id_b` second, but this would not drop the line if the same id is in 2 different columns.

Comment: What would you want to do if the second appearance of one ID is in the same row as the first appearance of another ID?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [tour], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do `stack` with `unstack` + `duplicated`

```
df=df[~df[['id_a','id_b']].stack().duplicated().unstack().any(1)]
  id_a id_b   value
0  NWS  HRD   21.06
1  HPE  ZRF  170.13
3  HBI  BCT  304.37
4  JFK  AQE  314.12
```